# Set a DataContext through DataTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, datacontext

I am having an issue setting a datacontext to controls inside datatemplates when instantiating them through a DataTemplateSelector.

Here's my **CustomView** code structure.

I have a **ListBox** to which I assign a list of items to populate.

Some **DataTemplates** are defined in the **CustomView** as resources:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
      <views:CustomControl DataContext="{Binding ???}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
      <views:CustomControl DataContext="{Binding ???}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Each of the ListBox items goes through a **DataTemplateSelector**.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Change" Width="330">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ResolverTemplateSelector}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

All the **ResolverTemplateSelector** does is checking a property on the current Item and return the proper DataTemplate:

```
CustomControl control = GetRootControl(container);

if (Item is ObjectType object)
{
    DataTemplate template;
    switch (object.Property)
    {
        case PropertyValue1:
            template = FindTemplateFromString("Template1", control);
            break;

        case PropertyValue2:
            template = FindTemplateFromString("Template2", control);
            break;
    }
    object.DataTemplate = template;
    return template;
```

This works fine, the template is set and I can see it in the view.
The problem is that I can't set the **DataContext** of the **CustomControl** instantiated in the template with what I need.
I need to set its **DataContext** with a property stored in the **ViewModel** of the **CustomView**.
I tried:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
    <views:CustomControl DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:CustomView}}, Path=DataContext}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

To at least try to have the DataContext being the same of the CustomView, so I could access its properties in the code behind, but no luck. The DataContext is always **null**.

Any idea? Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The datacontext of each thing in an attempt temscontrol is the item. You bind the itemssource. Templating creates ui for each row and the datacontext of each is the corresponding item. It's also very common to use datatype to associate a datatemplate with a row/item viewmodel type. Datatemplateselectors are necessary in uwp apps but rare in wpf.

Comment: To put this another way. You already have a datacontext. The datatemplateselector is selecting a datatemplate that's going to be used to produce UI for that datacontext ( of the row ).

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, but looking in locals or trying to access it throws an exception as DataContext of those items (the CustomControl spawned in those items) it's always null.

Comment: Your binding would usually work. But in this special case it doesn't. This is because the columns of the `GridView` are not part of the logical tree. In this case the `Binding.RelativeSource` cannot be resolved, if the source is outside the template.

Comment: What is the reason that the visuals of your items is not based on the data item it represents? It seems your data design needs some refactoring. All information the item template needs should be provided by the item's model (the `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate`).

Answer (score 0):

In the end I could make this work.
For anyone else trying the same thing:

```
  <views:CustomControl DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ParentView, Path=TargetViewModel}"/>
```